# Grouping and Running a For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm looking to include a group statement within my for loop and I'm having difficulty finding any details into how to properly do this.

The example below , calculates the Extra, Outstanding and Current Column within my loop statement. I'm trying to group by id so that the loop will restart with every id. My current code:

```
dat <- tibble(
id = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B"),
rn= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2),
current = c(100,0,0,0,0,0,500,0),
paid = c(10,12,12,13,13,13,20,20),
pct_extra = c(.02,.05,.05,.07, .03, .01, .09,.01),
Extra = NA,
Outstanding = NA)

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
dat$Extra[i] <- dat$current[i]*dat$pct_extra[i]
dat$Outstanding[i] <- dat$current[i] - dat$paid[i] - dat$Extra[i]
if(i < nrow(dat)){
dat$current[(i+1)] <- dat$Outstanding[i]}}
```

I saw other posts with this same question and they seem to revert to using dplyr. So my first attempt was:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
 dat%>%
    group_by(id)%>%
    mutate(Extra=pct_extra*(current-paid),
           Outstanding=current-paid-Extra,
           current=if_else(rn==1,current,lag(Outstanding)))}
```

But this attempt didnt actually calculate the Extra, Outstanding and current columns which my guess is because I'm not using the loop statement properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions/references on how I can include a group statement into my for loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. `for` loops (surrounding dplyr pipes) are generally not necessary with `dplyr` grouping, this is no exception (though we will use your `for` loop in a "single group at a time" way).
2. Even if it were, you loop with `i` and never use `i`, so you're doing the same calculation to all rows, `nrow(dat)` times.
3. Third, you aren't storing the results.

My first attempt (after realizing the *rolling* nature of this) was to try to adapt `slider::slide` to it, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.

In older-`dplyr`, I would `dat %>% group_by(id) %>% do({...})`, but they've superseded `do` in lieu of `across` and multi-row `summarize` (which I could not figure out how to make do this).

So then I realized that your `for` loop works fine, it just needs to be applied one group at a time.

```r
func <- function(z) {
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(z))) {
    z$Extra[i] <- z$current[i]*z$pct_extra[i]
    z$Outstanding[i] <- z$current[i] - z$paid[i] - z$Extra[i]
    if (i < nrow(z)) {
      z$current[(i+1)] <- z$Outstanding[i]
    }
  }
  z
}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # nest, unnest
library(purrr) # map, can be done with base::Map as well

dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest(quux = -id) %>%
  mutate(quux = map(quux, func)) %>%
  unnest(quux) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 7
#   id       rn current  paid pct_extra  Extra Outstanding
#   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 A         1   100      10      0.02  2            88  
# 2 A         2    88      12      0.05  4.4          71.6
# 3 A         3    71.6    12      0.05  3.58         56.0
# 4 A         4    56.0    13      0.07  3.92         39.1
# 5 A         5    39.1    13      0.03  1.17         24.9
# 6 A         6    24.9    13      0.01  0.249        11.7
# 7 B         1   500      20      0.09 45           435  
# 8 B         2   435      20      0.01  4.35        411.
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! The results look correct for `id = A` but not for B. When `rn=1` for `id = B` and `row = 1` the current should be equal to 500. It looks like your results dont distinguish between A and B.

Comment: Okay, I had used the `dat` from your question *after* the faulty code, my fault. I now have the first `current` for `B` as 500, and the first `Outstanding` (for that row) as 436.8, is that correct? (In other words ... the code is right, the input data was wrong. Did you try it yourself?)

Comment: Yes I did try it. The results are incorrect and seems like the logic being processed by r is getting mixed. For example, row 2 for id = A. The `current` is 88.2 (which is correct), the `paid` is 12 and `pct_extra` is .05. Based on the formulas within the mutate function...`Extra` should equal  this should be 3.81 (.05*(88.2-12) and `Outstanding` should be  72.39 (88.2-12-3.81).

Comment: Oh, you want a rolling calculation. Ok, that's different (and not at all intuitive in `dplyr`). Sorry, you had a `for` loop and I skipped over that part in my head.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much!